# How to Send Voice over Unity Networking - UNET

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer, unet, voice

I am able to **Record and Run Audio** from my **Microphone** using this code snippet:

```
  void OnGUI() {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), "record")) {
           // Microphone.End(Microphone.devices[0]);
            audsourceAttached.clip = Microphone.Start(Microphone.devices[0], false, 3, 44100);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 30, 100, 20), "Stop"))
        {
            //Microphone.End(Microphone.devices[0]);
            audsourceAttached.Play();
        }
    }
```

Now I am willing to **send this audio across Network** (on my local network-another instance of the game). How can I do this?

I tried to find this on google but unable to find any useful solution/links.

**How can I send audio through microphone like real-time Chat in a game/etc.**

Comment: Unhelpful comment: please don't. Many gamers never want the game to transmit audio. We already have Skype, Steam, Teamspeak, and many many **many** other solutions for that, and your game will interfere with them.

Comment: I don't see this as a problem, as long as you can turn it off in favour of Skype, Steam, Teamspeak, etc. 

Also, there are some edge cases where microphone audio gets used in combination with its source location instead of a traditional voice chat, i.e. it's only audible if you're close enough to the speaking player in the game. I think for example DayZ and/or ArmA do this.

Comment: Here may be some code that interests you: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/737002/wav-byte-to-audioclip.html

Comment: I agree that there are plenty of reasons to integrate voice chat directly into the game instead of relying on 3rd party tools. It allows to connect players to each other ad-hoc when they meet in an open world or in a game lobby. In a team-based game with no respawn you can also prevent dead players from talking to the living. But keep in mind that just getting the waveform and sending it over the network might not give you very good results. It would be better to encode it in an audio codec which is made for voice encoding in realtime over low-bandwidth.

Comment: @Philipp maybe you are right but i just share my efforts that what i have done so far. Is there anyother details please share your complete answer

Comment: @Peter if there any third party solution that can intergrate with unity3d please share your answer. This can be good resource for future user beside my question.

Comment: @Peter voice-chat can be used as a means of *immersion* for players actively seeking out that experience. E.g. have a game where you first have to find a radio to communicate with others, or a spacegame where other players can potentially listen in to your frequencies if you don't have expensive enough radio / or even jam your radio when pirates attack you - there's always people that do not like immersion, they can use external solutions anyways...

Comment: Consider recording everything into an mp3 which has a nice file format for streaming. Then send the latest frame over the network. Every player should buffer the frame and play it.

Comment: @ateesdalejr how, this is the question

Comment: https://github.com/hecomi/uNetVoice This project works great for voice chat and audio recording in Unity 5 and version 2018, I haven't tested it with others yet.

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: You can't do it natively in Unity

[`Microphone.Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.Start.html) returns an [`AudioClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html) which has [3 load types](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClipLoadType.html), none of which fit your use case. All of them (even the [`.Streaming`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClipLoadType.Streaming.html) one) require the entire clip to be on the users computer already. Using [`AudioClip.GetData()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.GetData.html) and sending a file over the network (in Unity, using [`Networking.NetworkTransport.Send()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkTransport.Send.html)) would be horribly unresponsive and can only actually occur after the recording finishes its clip. This ignores audio codecs, using multiple threads (Unity isn't thread safe), and dealing with the real time nature of audio device data.

What you need is a way to get the audio device data in real time which Unity provides no mechanism for and therefore cannot support RTC natively. [This answer comes to the same conclusion](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1348039/how-to-let-players-talk-in-real-time-to-each-other-1.html)

Third party solutions exist on the asset store. Here's one such solution mentioned in the above linked answer: [Dissonance Voice Chat](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/47846). Going through the files list it uses a native .dll, the [Opus](http://opus-codec.org/downloads/) audio codec, and a bunch of C# files for interfacing with the native code.

Rolling your own, which I do not recommend, would require doing the following:

- Using a separate C# `System.Threading` thread to process your audio so that your framerate and audio playback aren't coupled together.
- Getting the audio data isn't trivial in C#. .NET uses [`DirectSound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318673(v=vs.85).aspx) which is a Windows things.  [Mono doesn't support this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420163/is-directsound-supported-on-mono). This means you either need to implement a cross platform solution yourself natively, or rely on a library that already does.
- Transporting it over the network requires a socket using [.NET sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx). These seem robust and are supported in Mono.
- Your sockets should transport as a P2P multicast. This allows you to send one audio stream to multiple people all at once. It also skips a setup like `Client ==> Server ==> Client` which adds extra latency.
- You would also want a codec to make sure that you're not just sending uncompressed audio willy-nilly. There are many out there which most likely requires interfacing with another native library.